# Suggested edits: is this spam?

Tags: support, spam-handling

I'm sure it is, but just checking that this indeed happens to the system. Anyway, who would waste time in such ridiculous and useless thing?

[image]

PS: linked question is about blocking spam, not about ID. It does not contain any mention about **audit** at all.

Comment: It is an audit. The system just inserts random words in some posts, to make sure you are reading them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suggested Edits spam](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8095/suggested-edits-spam)

Comment: Hmm maybe that's not the best dupe, they are usually audits as @MarkKirby suggests... I can't seem to find the best dupe, definitely this question has been asked before

Comment: Well, that question is probably more ambitious (about blocking them). This is more about ID. In fact, the other post **does not contain the word audit**. So I don't think it is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: ID? Sorry I don't understand what you mean. The linked post is not the ideal dupe, although it seems to be exactly like your question, but the action advised in the answer is the same, you should just reject with reason: "Spam or vandalism" that is the correct action and you will pass the audit if you take it. Sometimes we do get real spam like this too

Comment: Not really a duplicate @Zanna, I don't think, because that was actual spam, whereas this is a system imposed audit.

Comment: @Seth I spent ages trying to find the right one this morning, then someone in chat found me that one, and I was too quick in voting. I will retract my vote, but it's driving me crazy that I can't find the real dupe!!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like vandalism to me. But as suggested it's an audit to determine if you are paying attention.